# Can I somehow interactively debug a compiled JavaScript/React project that only works when hosted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, debugging, webpack

We have a project setup that I expect is pretty common, and I am looking for a better/any way to properly debug it. I have taken over the project, so I'm not the one who set it up like this, nor can I get permission to make major changes to the basic process:

- the project is in JavaScript and React
- the project is compiled via Webpack (with the dev-watch option to allow for incremental recompiles)
- the resulting pack is copied to a (local) web server, which hosts it as part of a client-server application
- the client cannot in any sensible way run without being hosted by the server (due to various state and config data being dynamically generated by the server and injected)

The problem I now face: no matter whether I want to inspect a variable, add a logging statement, change a branch condition, everything involves shift-reloading the server page to get the entire new client package, nuking any state and requiring a lengthy process from logging in to reaching the point I was working on.

Is there no way to somehow let VSCode (or honestly any other, for a feature like that I'd switch IDEs if I had to) tap into the browser tab and somehow connect the source code and/or let me inspect variables, set breakpoints, anything like that ? This kind of thing is trivially possible with other languages I am more familiar with such as PHP, Java, etc., so I'm wondering if I am missing something obvious.